# applying class to parent if child has it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jQuery when I have this HTML code I need to add the class name to the parent li only when the  child has the class name high.

thanks.

```
<li class="emergency" style="background-color: #FE9D9D;">
<span class="high">250</span></li>
```

Comment: Something like this: `$('li:has(span.high)').addClass('className');`?

Answer (score 2):

You can target .high class like this then use closest() to get the parent li.

```
$('li .high').closest('li').addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('li:has("span.high")').addClass('className');
```

li `has` span element with class `high` addCass `className` to it.

[.addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/aks3k/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
$('li:has("span.high")').addClass('newClass');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SSr4Z/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".high").parent().addClass('sss');
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M5gNA/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to add the class of the `span` also to the parent `li`, right?

```
$('li .high').closest('li').addClass('high');
```